# Why can't a custom ListView have it's own xaml file?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Why can't my custom ListView have it's own xaml file? I have a custom Button and it works with a xaml file with no issues, but not my ListView. The main reason I want to use this approach (rather than be forced to create a Style that is place in the Generic.xaml file) is because I would like to take advantage of the Resources element and place all resources related to the listview within the xaml file:

```
public sealed partial class MyListView : ListView
{
    public MyListView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And here is the associated xaml file:

```
<ListView
        x:Class="App1.MyListView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:App1"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="300"
        d:DesignWidth="400">

<ListView.Resources>
    <!-- I would like to place all related resources here instead of having
    them placed in external locations, and then have to open different files to find them. -->
</ListView.Resources>

</ListView>
```

Comment: What happens when you attempt to do so?  Do you receive an error?

Comment: I receive a "XAML parsing failed." error. The error appears to come from the InitializeComponent() method.

Comment: Would need to see more of your implementation to troubleshoot the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Instead of creating a xaml file for the list, you can create a `ResourceDictionary` called `MyCustomList_Styles.xaml` and put all the `List` related `Styles` there.

Answer (score 3):

Although I would expect this should work as well, it seems that this problem is present and [it is recommended to use the templated control instead](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8b5ff740-9f66-4f68-b168-aa8faac02496/uwpxamlxaml-parsing-failed-when-subclassing-listboxlistviewgridview?forum=wpdevelop).

I suppose the problem is that assigning the compiler is unable to generate the valid assignment to the `Items` property of the control, which it is trying to construct from the content of the element. Even when the element is closed immediately it seems to be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your response lead me to come up with my own little "hack", if you will. What I did was I wraped the call to InitializeComponent() within try-catch block. So I guess it is at least allowing me to add resources to the xaml file now. Would you mind testing this out yourself and see if you get the same result? If this approach works consistently then I will definitely implement it into my workflow until Microsoft provides a "fix". I say that because people say that having a xaml file works with no problem in WPF.

Comment: If you examine the InitializeComponent() method by peeking its definition, you will see that the Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent() method causes the problem. Moral of story: You can use the "try-catch hack" as long as the LoadComponent() method is not changed by Microsoft in a way that stops it from loading the xaml file's resources before whatever causes the error is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Why not place resources on the Page or inside ListView, rather than deriving your own control?

```
<Page
x:Class="ListViewResources.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ListViewResources"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <!-- Place all related resources here instead of having them placed in external locations, and then have to open different files to find them. -->
</Page.Resources>


<ListView x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <!-- Or place related resources here -->
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>

</Page>
```